# aws import image (create ami) call is failing with InternalError

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to execute boto3 api import_image which basically takes disk description and trigger import image task and returns a response which contains task id.

> An error occurred (InternalError) when calling the ImportImage
>   operation: None

```
try:
    response = ec2_client.import_image(Description = description, DiskContainers = disk_containers)
    response_import_image_task_id = response.get('ImportTaskId', None)
except Exception, fault:
     logger.error('awsDRLib<initiate_import_image>: '%s' %str(fault))
     #InternalError is caught here.
     logger.traceback(fault)
     raise fault
#also retrying the operation and later receiving error ResourceCountExeceeded.
```

This error is random and there is no permission issue with aws instance. I am retrying on this operation. and getting same error 4-5 times and after that getting "ResourceCountExceeded".

I can understand that ResourceCountExceeded comes when there are ongoing import image operation more than permissible limit. But since InternalError is coming in start then there should not have been started import image operation.

Is there any api which can tell how many import image operations are going on..??
Kindly help to rectify this issue.